# NSTimer updating progress view block UI

Tags: ios, progress-bar, nstimer

I have an NSTimer with interval 0.1 to updating a progress view which I am stopping as soon as it gets to 10 secs.
The progress view represents time from 0 seconds to 10 seconds. The reason which I am starting from 0.1-10 is because the progress view is smoother.

So this is working fine but randomly is blocking my UI for about 1-2 seconds.
This is the code:

```
  -(void)countFunction{

    secs=secs+0.1;

    if (secs>10.0 || continueTimer==NO) {
        [clockTimer invalidate];

        clockTimer=nil;
        clockLabel.alpha=0;
        [self stopRecorder];
    }

    progressView.progress=secs/10.0;
    NSLog(@"progress %f",secs/10.0);

    clockLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",secs];
```

}

```
  -(void)countdown{

secs=0.0;
clockTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1 target:self selector:@selector(countFunction) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

}
```

I tried to use GCD but the UI was not updating. Any suggestion how to fix this issue?

Comment: Isn't your timer callback called on a background thread? If so then you need to use 'dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue'... To make updates to UI objects.

Comment: I tried dispatch async but it wasn't updating the interface.

Comment: NSTimer callbacks are on the main thread.